# This is a c program to find next greatest number with same digits. But not passing one test case

Tags: c, debugging, output

This is a C program to find the next greater number with the same digits. This program is working for all given test cases except one. When the input is `472`, the expected output is `724`. But my output is `247`. Can anyone please help me to find the error?

logic I tried to solve this is :

1. Traverse the given number from rightmost digit, keep traversing till you find a digit which is smaller than the previously traversed digit. For example, if the input number is `534976`, we stop at `4` because `4` is smaller than next digit `9`. If we do not find such a digit, then output is `Not Possible`.
2. Now search the right side of above found digit ‘d’ for the smallest digit greater than ‘d’. For `534976`, the right side of `4` contains `976`. The smallest digit greater than `4` is `6`.
3. Swap the above found two digits, we get `536974` in above example.
4. Now sort all digits from position next to ‘d’ to the end of number. The number that we get after sorting is the output. For above example, we sort digits in bold `536974`. We get `536479` which is the next greater number for input `534976`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int N, dig[100], i = 0,j, temp, t, s, k, l, min, temp1;

    scanf("%d", &N);
    while (N > 0) {
        dig[i] = N % 10;
        i++;
        N = N / 10;
    }

    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        if (dig[j] > dig[j + 1]) {
            s = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    min = dig[s];
    //printf("%d ", min);
    for (k = s; k >= 0; k--) {
        if (dig[k] <= min) {
            min = dig[k];
            t = k;
        }
    }
    //printf("%d ", t);
    temp = dig[t];
    dig[t] = dig[s + 1];
    dig[s + 1] = temp;
    for (k = 0; k <= s; k++) {
        for (l = k + 1; l <= s; l++) {
            if (dig[k] < dig[l]) {
                temp1 = dig[k];
                dig[k] = dig[l];
                dig[l] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        printf("%d", dig[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic of the program is not very clear. Please describe it.

Comment: Now I attached the logic I tried sir.

Comment: Are the digits unique?

Comment: `for(j=0;j<=i;j++)` Is suspicious (out of "bounds", not of the allocated array, but of the number of digits), and `if(dig[j]>dig[j+1])` too.

Comment: Is *next greatest* not supposed to convey that the output should be strictly less than the input?  Or do you mean "next great*er*"?

Comment: `for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(dig[j]>dig[j+1])` likely should be `for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(dig[j-1]>dig[j])` .

Comment: @JohnBollinger "Next greatest" means that if you generate the complete set of distinct permutations of the digits in the provided number, and then sort them numerically, the correct answer is the number that immediately follows the input value in that sorted list.

Comment: @Bob's comment is correct that the code potentially accesses array members that aren't part of the number. Also the code doesn't do any error checking, e.g. after the first `for` loop, nothing checks whether a valid `s` was found. But the core problem is that `if(dig[k]<=min)` should be `if(dig[k]<=min && dig[k] > dig[s+1])`. In other words, the code is finding the smallest digit after the 4, which is 2. But it should be finding the smallest digit after the 4 which is greater than 4, which is 7.

Comment: That's not helpful, @dgnuff, without specifying the sort order.  But in any case, I assure you that to me, "next greatest" relative to a number *n* means a number **smaller** than *n*.  From biggest to smallest there is the greatest, then the next greatest, then the next next greatest, ....

Comment: I would encourage you to work with numeric strings rather than actual numbers.  Among the advantages are (1) you already have an array (the string), so you don't need to convert back and forth; (2) you don't have to worry about arithmetic overflow.

Comment: I would furthermore *urge* you to use more meaningful names for your variables.  The extra time spent typing will pay off many times over in easier development, debugging, and maintenance.

Comment: What?  This code isn't Fortran77? :P

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm seems correct, but the loops are incorrect. Some index boundaries are off by one and the comparisons with `<=` are incorrect. Storing the digits by increasing powers of 10, while more practical is counter-intuitive and complicates the translation of the algorithm into code.

Here is a corrected version, that outputs all greater numbers. You can easily check the output by piping through `sort -c` to verify order and `wc -l` to verify that all combinations have been found (there should be at most **n! - 1** greater numbers for a number with **n** digits).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N, dig[100], i, j, s, t, k, l, temp;

    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1 || N < 0)
        return 1;

    for (;;) {
        for (i = j = 100; N > 0;) {
            dig[--i] = N % 10;
            N = N / 10;
        }
        for (s = j - 2; s >= i; s--) {
            if (dig[s] < dig[s + 1]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (s < i) {
            /* no greater number with the same digits */
            break;
        }
        t = s + 1;
        for (k = t + 1; k < j; k++) {
            if (dig[k] < dig[t] && dig[k] > dig[s]) {
                t = k;
            }
        }
        temp = dig[t];
        dig[t] = dig[s];
        dig[s] = temp;
        for (k = s + 1; k < j; k++) {
            for (l = k + 1; l < j; l++) {
                if (dig[k] > dig[l]) {
                    temp = dig[k];
                    dig[k] = dig[l];
                    dig[l] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        N = 0;
        for (k = i; k < j; k++) {
            N = N * 10 + dig[k];
            printf("%d", dig[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input: `472`

Output:

```
724
742
```